# Lambda gives No such file or directory(cant find the script file) error while running a bash script inside container. But this is successful in local

Tags: bash, docker, function, lambda, containers

I am creating a lambda function from a docker image, this docker image actually runs a bash script inside of the docker container but when I tried to test that then it gives this following error. But this is successful in local. I tested with commented and uncommented entrypoint. Please help me to figure it out.
The dockerfile -

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli
USER root
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION ap-south-1
# RUN mkdir /tmp
COPY main.sh /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN chmod +x main.sh
RUN touch file_path_final.txt
RUN touch file_path_initial.txt
RUN touch output_final.json
RUN touch output_initial.json
RUN chmod 777 file_path_final.txt
RUN chmod 777 file_path_initial.txt
RUN chmod 777 output_final.json
RUN chmod 777 output_initial.json

RUN yum install jq -y
# ENTRYPOINT ./main.sh ; /bin/bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c" , "ls && ./tmp/main.sh"]
```

The error -

```
START RequestId: 8d689260-e500-45d7-aac8-ae260834ed96 Version: $LATEST
/bin/sh: ./tmp/main.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./tmp/main.sh: No such file or directory
END RequestId: 8d689260-e500-45d7-aac8-ae260834ed96
REPORT RequestId: 8d689260-e500-45d7-aac8-ae260834ed96  Duration: 58.29 ms  Billed Duration: 59 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB   
RequestId: 8d689260-e500-45d7-aac8-ae260834ed96 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 127
Runtime.ExitError
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i did it to Run A C++ over a bash script :

```
#Pulling the node image from the AWS WCR PUBLIC docker hub.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2.2022.10.11.10

#Setting the working directory to /home.
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR}
#Copying the contents of the current directory to the working directory.
COPY . .
#This is installing ffmpeg on the container.
RUN yum update -y

# Install sudo, wget and openssl, which is required for building CMake
RUN yum install sudo wget openssl-devel -y
# Install development tools
RUN sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y

# Download, build and install cmake

RUN yum install -y make 
#RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.22.3/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz && tar -zxvf cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz && cd ./cmake-3.22.3 && ./bootstrap && make && sudo make install
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ libcurl-devel cmake3 git
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/ctest3 /usr/bin/ctest
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/cpack3 /usr/bin/cpack
# get cmake versin
RUN cmake --version
RUN echo $(cmake --version)
#This is installing the nodejs and npm on the container.
RUN ./build.sh

RUN chmod 755 run.sh bootstrap
#This is running the nodejs application.
CMD [ "run.sh" ]
```

You will need a bootstrap file in the root directory : ([FROM DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html))

```
#!/bin/sh

set -euo pipefail

# Initialization - load function handler
source $LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/"$(echo $_HANDLER | cut -d. -f1).sh"

# Processing
while true
do
  HEADERS="$(mktemp)"
  # Get an event. The HTTP request will block until one is received
  EVENT_DATA=$(curl -sS -LD "$HEADERS" -X GET "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next")

  # Extract request ID by scraping response headers received above
  REQUEST_ID=$(grep -Fi Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id "$HEADERS" | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d: -f2)

  # Run the handler function from the script
  RESPONSE=$($(echo "$_HANDLER" | cut -d. -f2) "$EVENT_DATA")

  # Send the response
  curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response"  -d "$RESPONSE"
done
```